# Se queda bloqueado sin sentido Linux Server

Tags: linux, servidor

Últimamente estoy sufriendo congelación "random" del servidor que se queda en negro y no responde. 
Los clientes dejan de funcionar (Esta montado un ldap, es un servidor Lliurex). Lo ultimo que ocurre en el log antes de "explotar" es el siguiente código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque pasa esto, y no he tocado nada desde que iba siempre bien, hasta ahora. La versión de lliurex es 16.04 (La ultima LTS).

**EDIT 0:** Se ha vuelto a congelar sin sentido alguno, miro sobre las 8:40 todo iba bien y al rato, sobre las 9:00 se ha quedado congelado, no respondía nada, ni teclado ni ratón.

**EDIT 1:** Mi procesador actual es "AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor", 8GB RAM, y grafica GT218 [GeForce 210].

Comment: ps el error posiblemente sea "inserted module" te recomiendo una pregunta similar aqui : https://askubuntu.com/questions/809199/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules-ubuntu-16-04 y  https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/07/msg01442.html

Comment: Pero ese codigo solo ocurre despues de reiniciar, luego hay una serie de lineas en el log, listando todo el inicio. Sobretodo esto pasa los fin de semana cuando no hay actividad en el servidor y se queda congelado.

Comment: implementas : IDS en tu servidor?, te sugiero hacer un analisis en tu server y mirar las ultimas entras a el?, tuve un problema similar que se me congelaba el servidor y era que alguien queria  entrar en el sin permiso.

Comment: Que se supone que es IDS y que hace?

Comment: no conoces IDS? o mejor dicho en tu caso:" Web Intrusion Detection"  El Web Intrusion Detection System (Web IDS) analiza los archivos de registro de acceso generados por un servidor web. Analiza estos archivos para detectar ataques al servidor web, si no tienes una configuracion si yo podria atacar tu servidor y posiblemente nunca sabrias que lo estoy haciendo tiempo despues lo sabrias, https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TRM/GC32-1323-00/en_US/HTML/admin169.htm,https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/network-intrusion-detection-tools/#gref

Comment: Mi servidor no tiene salida a internet, es solo un servidor local, no puedes atacarlo desde fuera y no dispone de un servidor Web instalado actualmente.

Comment: mm dejame pensar

Comment: He añadido unos edit al post para mas información, si sirve para ayudarme @Simon

Answer (score 1):

Yo seguiría este procedimiento:

La ip que aparece la bloquearía con iptables.
Mientras tanto también actualizaría el SO.
Si tienes samba activo, si se puede desactívalo. 
Deja el servidor con los mínimos servicios, y vete activándolos según pase el tiempo sin caídas.

Si sigue cayéndose, entonces sube el verbose del log del samba/ldap hasta que des con el problema.

Se suelen arreglar estos problemas con la actualización. Si se arreglara bloqueando la ip, ve a ver qué soft y versión del mismo está "atacando" para buscar incompatibilidades.